# GPS is not working in Samsung SM-J320F device

Tags: samsung, gps, location-services

I have tested with 3-4 GPS location apps in my `Samsung SM-J320F device` but still not getting location by using GPS. It's working fine to get Network based location. But i don't understand why it's failed with GPS? My device running with `Android 5.1.1`

Apps i tested with

- GPS Logger
- GPS Status & Toolbox
- GPS Essentials

Is there any setting that i missed? Is the issue in GPS Hardware chip?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well, arguing by the screenshot (especially the second and the last item in the list of notifications): Are you sitting in your room? That is, with walls around and a roof on top of you? Then that's the most likely explanation why the second-to-last notification tells you GPS found no satellites. GPS doesn't work indoors.

Comment: Yes i know that and also go outside with my device and make one trip but still no satellites fixed.

Comment: You could [check the logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) if they give some hints.